# jQuery conflicting with another on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue with my jQuery noConflict. The page that I'm trying to put the jQuery on has a drop-down navigation that already uses the noConflict() rule. Can I use more then one noConlfict on a page for different animations? I will have 3 different jQuery functions running simultaneously on one page. Separately they work fine, but once added together on a page they stop working. Below is one of the jQuery's that needs to run. Can someone help me add the noConflict() rule to it?

```
$(function() {
var current = 1;


var iterate = function(){
    var i = parseInt(current+1);
    var lis = $('#rotmenu').children('li').size();
    if(i>lis) i = 1;
    display($('#rotmenu li:nth-child('+i+')'));
}
display($('#rotmenu li:first'));
var slidetime = setInterval(iterate,5000);

$('#rotmenu li').bind('click',function(e){
    clearTimeout(slidetime);
    display($(this));
    e.preventDefault();
});

function display(elem){
    var $this   = elem;
    var repeat  = false;
    if(current == parseInt($this.index() + 1))
        repeat = true;

    if(!repeat)
        $this.parent().find('li:nth-child('+current+') a').stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'-20px'},300,function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'0.7'},700);
        });

    current = parseInt($this.index() + 1);

    var elem = $('a',$this);

        elem.stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'0px','opacity':'1.0'},300);

    var info_elem = elem.next();
    $('#rot1 .heading').animate({'left':'-420px'}, 500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
        $('h1',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_heading').html());
        $(this).animate({'left':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
    });

    $('#rot1 .description').animate({'bottom':'-270px'},500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
        $('p',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
        $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
    })
    $('#rot1').prepend(
    $('<img/>',{
        style   :   'opacity:0',
        className : 'bg'
    }).load(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},600);
        $('#rot1 img:first').next().animate({'opacity':'0'},700,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
).attr('src', info_elem.find('.info_image').html())
);
}
```

});

Comment: Just use `jQuery(function($) {...});` to wrap your code instead

Comment: Look you really need to include **one** version of jQuery, not one per widget.

Comment: @Pointy What if all the widgets called the same version of jQuery?

Comment: @user3015352 then you only need to import it once.

Answer (score 0):

As @adaneo already commented, you always should wrap you code into the jQuery method but after that you even should call noConflict with the first parameter *true*:

```
$.noConflict(true);
```

This removes your jQuery completely from the jQuery and $ variable and returns a jQuery object. You can use that return value to use it in your code by giving it to your object or method as parameter:

```
function MyFunction($) {
    $(doSomeThing);
}
MyFunction($.noConflict(true));
```